# Вычислить диапазон и найти в нем максимум

Tags: excel, max

Помогите составить форумулу. Есть 4 колонки с ценами биржевого актива. При условии, что E3>B3, надо найти максимальное значение из колонки High, но в диапазоне, начинающимся с данной строки и заканчивающимся перед строкой, после которой значение из колонки Low станет равным или меньше значению B3.

[Скрин таблицы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGySY.jpg)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ***Date*** | ***Open*** | ***High*** | ***Low*** | ***Close*** | ***max*** |
| 2 | 20.06.1983 | 169,13 | 170,1 | 168,59 | 169,02 |  |
| 3 | 21.06.1983 | **169,03** | **170,6** | 168,25 | **170,53** |  |
| 4 | 22.06.1983 | 170,53 | **171,6** | 170,42 | 170,99 |  |
| 5 | 23.06.1983 | 170,99 | **171** | 170,13 | 170,57 |  |
| 6 | 24.06.1983 | 170,57 | **170,69** | 170,03 | 170,41 |  |
| 7 | 27.06.1983 | 170,4 | 170,46 | **168,32** | 168,46 |  |
| 8 | 28.06.1983 | 168,45 | 168,81 | 165,67 | 165,68 |  |
| 9 | 29.06.1983 | 165,78 | 166,64 | 165,43 | 166,64 |  |
| 10 | 30.06.1983 | 167,64 | 167,64 | 167,64 | 167,64 |  |
| 11 | 01.07.1983 | 168,11 | 168,64 | 167,77 | 168,64 |  |
| 12 | 05.07.1983 | 166,55 | 168,64 | 167,77 | 168,64 |  |
| 13 | 06.07.1983 | 166,71 | 168,88 | 166,49 | 168,48 |  |
| 14 | 07.07.1983 | 168,48 | 169,15 | 167,08 | 167,56 |  |

Т.е. грубо говоря, нужно знать, как высоко цена уходила от цены открытия, пока вновь к ней не вернулась. В данном случае ответ будет 171.6.

[файл](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6NJd/mWg7yseXR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ЕСЛИ(E2>B2;ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(D3:$D$20;"<="&B2);МАКС(C2:ИНДЕКС($C$1:$C$20;МИН(ЕСЛИ(D3:$D$20<=B2;СТРОКА(D3:$D$20)-1)))););)
```

Формула массива, ввод тремя клавишами - *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.Если меньшее значение не найдено, формула вернет ноль. Если в этом случае вместо нуля надо получить максимум:

```
=ЕСЛИ(E2>B2;МАКС(C2:ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(D3:$D$20;"<="&B2);ИНДЕКС($C$1:$C$20;МИН(ЕСЛИ(D3:$D$20<=B2;СТРОКА(D3:$D$20)-1)));$C$20));)
```

Comment: В вашем варианте формула возвращает мне значение из столбца High, которое находится на строчку выше, чем первое значение из столбца Low, меньшее, чем цена открытия. Т.е. в моем примере ваша формула возвращает мне 170.69. А мне надо не последнее значение C6, а наибольшее из массива С3:C6, в данном случае 171,6.

Comment: Изменил формулу

Comment: К сожалению, если значение не найдено, формула возвращает не ошибку, а просто какую-то произвольную котировку. Например, переделала под падение, в строке 9719 (04/01/22) открытие 4804.51, и цена по сей день цена к нему не вернулась, т.е. в колонке high не найдено значение, превышающее 4804.51. Формула мне выдает 147,26 (столбец "min"). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fu20um4gCQIzuUdnJwwWgO08zvSfHcXt/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=101533425831344708468&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Еще раз изменил - теперь с проверкой на наличие меньшего значения. Измените нижние границы диапазонов

Comment: Теперь получается, что если в колонке Low нет значения, меньшего чем цена открытия B2, с которой идет сравнение, тогда формула выдает ноль, хотя должна выдавать максимум из диапазона C2:$C$20, т.к. цена же выросла в итоге) https://prnt.sc/pmxYISnq1yJn

Comment: Знать бы всю логику Вашей работы :) Добавил.